# Suggestions on how to make search bar responsive

Tags: html, css, media-queries

The search bar on my site is not responsive. What is the best way to make it responsive? Check the width of the screen of the device and change the focus width and height in the css according, or are there more effective way to handle according the device it's width? The code I have in place so far is shown below, html and css.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);
@import url(https://raw.github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/docs/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css);

}
#wrap {
  margin: 50px 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #555;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.795, 0.000, 1.000);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"]:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 700px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  cursor: text;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  height: 67px;
  width: 63px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:red;
  float: right;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
      <form action="" autocomplete="on">
      <input id="search" name="Zoek" type="text" placeholder="U zoekt?"><input id="search_submit" value="Verstuur" type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Use `%` instead of hardcoded width.

Comment: `input[type="text"]:focus {
      width: 90%;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);
@import url(https://raw.github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/docs/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css);


#wrap {
  margin: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 700px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #555;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.795, 0.000, 1.000);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"]:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: calc(100% - 70px);
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  cursor: text;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  height: 67px;
  width: 63px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:red;
  float: right;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  input[type="submit"]  {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-size: 30px 30px;
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  input[type="text"]:focus {
    width: calc(100% -35px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
      <form action="" autocomplete="on">
      <input id="search" name="Zoek" type="text" placeholder="U zoekt?"><input id="search_submit" value="Verstuur" type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t0z0bpry/1/)

Comment: This sure works, even in the columns of the site it stays between the available space. I tried to extend the solution to the height, because on a mobile device it takes a bit too much of the screen. I don't have much experience with multiple devices to serve, is it common practice to set the max-height by using 'vh'?

Comment: you meant, need to make smaller on small screen or can you show screenshot or something what are expecting

Comment: I meant to set the height of the search box, icon and text to a lesser height on a mobile device. No screenshot in place because have not yet build that part.

Comment: Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/t0z0bpry/1/

Comment: You can use media queries. I have use max-width: 600px for small screen but you can write your own

Comment: Clear to work it out with the max-width. If, for reasons of putting the magnifier on a certain place in the header because the navigation buttons are located next to the magnifier, the text input field needs to expand to the left, it is now limited to the column width. That may lead to too little space to write the search text. Is possible to expand the search input field over the navigation buttons? I tried visible: overflow; however that's not going to work, neither overflow-x: scroll;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171346/discussion-between-kumar-and-user2037412).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for your question. The change I have done is in the width of the input field.

`width: calc(100% - 63px);`

The 63px comes from the width you have given for `search_submit`.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);
@import url(https://raw.github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/docs/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css);

}
#wrap {
  margin: 50px 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 100;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #555;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: width .4s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.795, 0.000, 1.000);
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"]:focus:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: calc(100% - 63px);
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB;
  cursor: text;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  height: 67px;
  width: 63px;
  display: inline-block;
  color:red;
  float: right;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
      <form action="" autocomplete="on">
      <input id="search" name="Zoek" type="text" placeholder="U zoekt?"><input id="search_submit" value="Verstuur" type="submit">
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.search
{
    border: 2px solid #CF5C3F;
    overflow: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.search input[type="text"]
{
    border: 0px;
    width: 67%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.search input[type="text"]:focus
{
    outline: 0;
}

.search input[type="submit"]
{
    border: 0px;
    background: none;
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius-top-right: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-top-right: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius-top-right: 5px;
    border-radius-bottom-right: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottom-right: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius-bottom-right: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* ====== Medea Query for Search Box ====== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 780px)
{
    .search
    {
        width: 95%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <form class="search-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search for books, authors, categories and more..">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```